# VB6, Windows Tablets, Screen Resolution and ActiveResize

Tags: vb6, tablet, screen-resolution

Earlier this year, I moved my desktop from XP to the much-maligned 8.1. At about the same time, my Vista laptop expired and was replaced by a Windows 8.1 tablet. I kept the XP tower and this is used when programming in VB6.

All my VB6 programs work fine on my 8.1 desktop, but none do on the 8.1 tablet. Instead, I get an error message about “screen resolution”. This is where Stackoverflow comes in!

In searching on Google, I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252997/how-can-i-resize-my-vb6-program-so-that-it-automatically-fits-in-any-screen-reso), which was answered on Jul 21 '10 at 12:39 by Andy Robinson. Andy’s answer still left me with questions. I already use VB Gold’s Active Resize, which is Andy’s solution, but only after the Splash Screen. VB Gold says that no coding is necessary, but others seem to do so, as with a `Private Sub Form_Resize`. At my age, and not having done any new programming (as distinct from updating) for some time, I admit to needing help.

I want to be able to use some of my VB6 programs on a Windows Tablet. When I try to install, I get an error message about Screen Resolution. I think that VB Gold's ActiveResize, which is in these programs, should be able to do the job. But I am stuck with the coding.

My Tablet is a Dell Venue 8 Pro and the OS is Windows 8.1.

The total size of my 7 compiled VB6 programs is just under 14 Mb. I have connected a Memory Stick to the Tablet and sought to run the installation program. It is at that stage that I receive an error message regarding "Screen Resolution". The exact words are:

"Error: To install this program, your computer must have a display resolution of at least 800x600. Your computer's display resolution is 853x533".

From what I have read, ActiveResize should be able to solve the problem. But, at 80+, not all my faculties are working as I should wish!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Michael. Is there a question about re-sizing something buried in your post?

Comment: Micheal, can you please edit your question to add the specifics? What brand tablet running what version of windows? When you say "install", do you mean you are running an install program, or copying the files to the tablet? Does the error happen when you are installing, or when you try to start your application? What is the exact error message?

Comment: It sounds then like the error is not coming from your program, but from the installation program. Many installation programs have settings where you specify various minimum requirements. If you still have the installation projects you can update that and remove or decrease the screen size restrictions.